# Change window - check the location - from bottom to middle

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, in this fiction the image show up when image are all in the window. I need the image come up when it is at 75% or in the middle of the window. How i can do?

```
 $(window).on("load",function() {
      function fade(pageLoad) {
        var min = 0;
        var max = 1;
        var threshold = 0.01;

        $(".fade").each(function() {
          /* Check the location of each desired element */
          var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
          var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

          /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
          if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
            if ($(this).css("opacity")<=min+threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(300,max);}
          } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
            if ($(this).css("opacity")>=max-threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(300,min);}
          }
        });
      } fade(true); //fade elements on page-load
      $(window).scroll(function(){fade(false);}); //fade elements on scroll
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi have found this solution:

```
  $(window).on("load",function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winheight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $(".fade").each(function() {
          /* Check the location of each desired element */
          var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
          var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

          /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
          if ( windowBottom > (objectBottom - (winheight*0.65))) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
            if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
          } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
            if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
          }
        });
      }); $(window).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
    });
```